# How disable InfiniteGallery from responding to user Interaction

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I'm trying to disable user interaction on **com.blundell.tut.ui.view.InfiniteGallery**, I've done everything,

```
  android:clickable="false" 
  android:focusable="false"
  galleryOne.setClickable(false);
```

add click and focusable on layout to true, and all still not working. I just want to disable users from being able to interact with it. Any other idea would be welcomed. Thanks.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/galLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:focusable="false">

    <com.blundell.tut.ui.view.InfiniteGallery
        android:id="@+id/cardgallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:spacing="0dp"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ohw Mike, MIke, Mike, Mike I wanna give you a hug ahhhhhhh, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an `OnTouchListener` on the `InfiniteGallery` instance, and just return `true` in the `onTouch()` method to signal that the event has been handled. For example:

```
galleryOne.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
        {               
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```